# How come using a asyncScheduler keyword in a range operator postpones the subscription?

Tags: rxjs

When running the following source code in an Angular application, the 50 `Normal:` logger statements are displayed first and only then are displayed the 50 `Scheduler:` logger statements.

```
range(1, 50, asyncScheduler).subscribe((value: number) => console.log('Scheduler: ' + value));
range(1, 50).subscribe((value: number) => console.log('Noraml: ' + value));
```

Of course, removing the `asyncScheduler` keyword cancels this reverse display.

Why is that display being reversed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `asyncScheduler` doesn't postpone subscription. It only makes all emissions to be emitted asynchronously (just like wrapping each `next()` with `setTimeout()`).

RxJS is strictly synchronous unless you work with time or use asynchronous scheduler yourself. So when you use `range(1, 50)` it will emit all values synchronously in the same event before any emission from `asyncScheduler` can reach its observer. All 50 `next` emissions are stacked in the event queue waiting until the current event ends.